# Get key from Redis and expire it at the same time

Tags: node.js, redis

I have a Queue which is backed-up by Redis, with multiple node connections to that Redis server, and I need to make sure that it won't get the same key twice, so it will never run the same task more than once.

i'm using node-redis for this task:

```
client.set("some_key", data);
client.get("some_key", function (err, data) {
    //.. 
});
```

How can I make sure when getting that key that no other node process will be able to get it too? if I will set it as expired only after getting the value it won't be enough when 2 process will try to get the same value at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any other way than to wrap it in a MULTI

```
MULTI
GET some_key
DEL some_key
EXEC
```

So using node-redis, something like

```
 client.multi()
.get("some_key", data).del("some_key").
.exec(function (err, replies) {});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure atomicity of operations in Redis with `MULTI`/`EXEC` blocks and/or Lua scripting. In your case, you can do the `GET` followed by a `DEL` immediately afterward using either of the above approaches to ensure a single read.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a list with pop operations instead of a key. In particular you add new items to, say, the right, (via `rpush`) and pop them off the left ( via `LPOP`).

If you are storing a bunch if data in the key currently, such as a hash, use a unique identifier as the key of the hash and add that ID to the list instead. That way you get the get-and-remove capability in a simple fashion without needing transactions and multiple commands with the ability to store job data as well.

When the job succeeds delete the data key, if it fails you can re-queue it.

Comment: I wasn't farmiliar with the LPOP/RPUSH it does sounds like an approach i'd like to use instead. Thanks.